# Quantity not working on product single Ajax Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, ajax, woocommerce

I have recently added a cart to Ajax in my store. Everything works except quantity. When I choose the quantity. and then click on the button "add to cart" it always adds only one product.
I don't know how to get the value from INPUT into my "add to cart" button

My single-product.php input

```
<form>
   <input type="number" id="input" value="1" class="uneditable-input" />
</form>
```

My single-product.php button

```
<button type="submit"
    data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>"
    class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">
    <?php echo $label; ?>
</button>
```

I pasted **[this gist](https://gist.github.com/webaware/6260468)** into my functions.php file

Any ideas?